# int.TryParse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, Int32) on .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, type-conversion, .net-framework-version

This question was about IFormatProvider argument on int.TryParse

CultureInfo.CurrentCulture is passed to IFormatProvider to avoid culture related issues e.g 5.2 means decimal in some countries but in some it is thousand.

Why is this important? NumberStyles argument behaves regarding the CultureInfo e.g NumberStyles.AllowThousands detects the thousand regarding the culture info.

I deleted the question body because It was my fault and it was misleading (see below) and left what is important to upcoming developers.

my mistake:I was getting 5.0 even though it was an int and I couldn't figure out why. It was because of my culture info.

Comment: This works for me in a .NET 6 console app. `valid = true` and `result = 5` as expected. Also this is method is listed for .NET 6 on the MSDN page you have linked. I recommend you check your culture info as you may be using a culture that uses a different decimal separator other than a period. It looks like you may be in Turkey based on your link to the MSDN, in which case the decimal separator is a comma.

Comment: when you debug it what is your CultureInfo.CurrentCulture? depending on that the comma seperator is "." or ",". in the us "5.0" is ok to parse und de for example "5.0" is not valid but "5,0" is

Comment: Use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Comment: @RobKite thanks, it was my mistake, after creating decimal value based on current culture it worked. I have another question, "Also this is method is listed for .NET 6 on the MSDN page you have linked."? 6 is listed under .NET but not .NET framework and my project framework seems .NET 6.0. I thought ı had to check framework section in MSDN document. Why isn't that the case?

Comment: @theanonymous - .NET Framework refers to the older form (it stops at 4.8). .NET Core existed alongside .NET Framework for a little while but as of .NET Core 5 was renamed to .NET 5 and is the 'future of .NET' (they also skipped .NET Core 4 to avoid additional confusion). As such .NET Framework 6 doesn't exist, it's called .NET 6 and it's the continuation of .NET Core. Having written that out then yes it is a little confusing!

Comment: Usually when the cultureinfo is different, there may be some errors. Sometimes we have to notice these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct, however I suspect your current culture uses something other than a period (`.`) as a decimal separator. It looks like you may be in Turkey based on your link to the MSDN, in which case the decimal separator is a comma (`,`).

The below examples should help you figure out what is best to do in your use case.

```
// Build the number string using the current culture decimal separator
var decimalSeparator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
string numberString = $"5{decimalSeparator}0";
bool valid = int.TryParse(numberString, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out int result);
```

```
// Use a culture that uses a period as a decimal separator
string numberString = "5.0";
bool valid = int.TryParse(numberString, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"), out int result);
```

```
// Current culture must use a comma as a decimal separator
string numberString = "5,0";
bool valid = int.TryParse(numberString, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out int result);
```

Comment: yes, these are  the problem solutions